# Need help in placing label immediately after text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I am trying to place a label WIP (work in progress) immediately after text inside a disabled input box. I have tried few css configs but unable to achieve desired result.

Getting any help me really good for me.

Current code:

```
label.label-class {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    bottom: 13px;
  }


<div class="myclass">
    <mat-form-field class="form-input" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>MyLabel</mat-label>
        <input matInput [disabled]="true" [ngModel]="getName()" />
        <label class="label-class"> WIP </label>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Here is how it is appearing right now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if I understood you correctly; If you want to have the WIP label *after* the input, can't you just move the label outside of `mat-form-field`?
If that doesn't work, can you move the label outside of the div?

```css
label.label-class {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    bottom: 13px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
    <mat-form-field class="form-input" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>MyLabel</mat-label>
        <input matInput [disabled]="true" [ngModel]="getName()" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <label class="label-class"> WIP </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work. It caused hip to go down somewhere in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

```
.form-input {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.label-class{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

If you want them next to each other

```
.form-input {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: This will make WIP go to extreme right of the box. I need this to be just after the text.

Comment: Check the edit please

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now the input box length shrieked. I have not much idea on flex.

Answer (score -1):

Thw `::after` selector solves this issue.

```css
p::after { 
  content: " - Remember this";
}
```

```html
<h1>Demo of the ::after selector</h1>

<p>My name is Donald</p>
<p>I live in Ducksburg</p>
```

Comment: Please try to refrain from simply posting links to external resources and always make sure to include the most relevant facts into the post itself. Even when the post doesn't really solve the issue at hand...

Comment: @brezanac, Thanks for saying this.

I'm kind of new to contributing to StackOverflow. I have only used SOF for issues I face. I have never answered much to any questions before.

Comment: No worries. Welcome to SO.